# How to force extenal library to use SQL transaction

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have an external library to which I pass an instance of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and I want to wrap everything that library does on that connection in a transaction. When I was working with php/doctrine I would simply do exactly that in such cases - start a transaction in my code, call stuff on the library which issues DB queries and then commit the transaction in my code. When I tried to use this approach in C#, I got the following exception:

> ExecuteScalar requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

So I took a look at the library code and it always uses `SqlCommand` without setting the `Transaction` property. Is it possible to achieve my goal somehow? (changing the library code isn't feasible)

Comment: Post the code. If you use a `TransactionScope` both the connection and commands will run under an implicit transaction. I suspect you use an explicit transaction by calling `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction`

Comment: Ceck [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your code but I assume you tried to use an explicit transaction by calling `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()`.

You can use a TransactionScope to create an implicit transaction. Any connection, command created inside the TransactionScope's lifetime will be enlisted in a transaction automatically.

Copying from [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)'s example:

```
    // Create the TransactionScope to execute the commands, guaranteeing
    // that both commands can commit or roll back as a single unit of work.
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
        {
            // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the 
            // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
            connection1.Open();

            // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection1);
            returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);

            // If you get here, this means that command1 succeeded. By nesting
            // the using block for connection2 inside that of connection1, you
            // conserve server and network resources as connection2 is opened
            // only when there is a chance that the transaction can commit.   
            using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))
            {
                // The transaction is escalated to a full distributed
                // transaction when connection2 is opened.
                connection2.Open();

                // Execute the second command in the second database.
                returnValue = 0;
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection2);
                returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
            }
        }

        // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();

    }
```

The connection and both commands in this example run under a single transaction. Should an exception occur, the transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: Yes, I was using `BeginTransaction`. I'll try `TransactionScope`, seems like what I need. A small question - does this require that the connection is created inside the `TransactionScope`? Or will ones that were `new`ed before `new TransactionScope` also work?

Comment: @Xymanek you *shouldn't* have to do that in the first place. Connections are meant to be short-lived. Locks acquired during a connection's lifetime are held until that connection closes. Creating new connections is cheap thanks to connection pooling. You gain nothing by creating the connection outside the transaction scope. You can use `SqlConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current)` but you should try to avoid this. The answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257907/does-transactionscope-work-with-pre-existing-connections) explain both options

Comment: The connections were short lived, it was only a matter of where they were created... I've reorganized the code to create them inside the `TransactionScope` and it works perfectly, thanks! (turns out this issue was even simpler than I expected)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can use a [TransationScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.8), and everything will happen in the same transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Everything inside this block will be transactional:
    // Call the libraries which will use your SqlConnection here
}
```

Or you can use the [BeginTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=netframework-4.8) before calling the other library functions, and commit it after the function calls